# File.AppendText doesnt work after using File.Exists and File.Create

Tags: c#

As described i want to use File.AppendText or even a StreamWriter to append text to a file, but it doesn't work after executing File.Exists, File.Create and File.Delete.

My thought was because the objects both functions create weren't disposed when executing File.AppendText.

Here are the methods I used before trying to append text.

```
 private void erstelleLernsetDatei(string lernSetName)
    {
            //Sofern Datei doppelt erstellt wird
            if (File.Exists(speicherHinzufuegenForm.assemblyPfad + "/lernSetDateien/" + lernSetName + ".txt"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Datei exisitert schon");
            }
            else
            {
                File.Create(speicherHinzufuegenForm.assemblyPfad + "/lernSetDateien/" + lernSetName + ".txt");
            }
        
        hinzufuegenForm.aktualisiereComboBox(getLernsetDateien());
    }

private void gewaehltesLernsetLoeschen()
    {
        File.Delete(speicherHinzufuegenForm.assemblyPfad + "/lernsetDateien/" + speicherHinzufuegenForm.gewaehltesLernset + ".txt");
        speicherHinzufuegenForm.gewaehltesLernset = "";
        
    }
```

And this is the function to append the text:

```
public void hinzufuegenVokabeln(string begriff, string definition)
    {
        if (speicherHinzufuegenForm.gewaehltesLernset != "")
        {
            File.AppendAllText(speicherHinzufuegenForm.assemblyPfad + speicherHinzufuegenForm.gewaehltesLernset + ".txt", $"{begriff},{definition};");
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Wähle zunächst ein Lernset");
        }
    }
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Where do you assign a value to `gewaehltesLernset `? Have you used the debugger to see what happens? However, if yoo use `AppendAllText` it will always work, no lmatter if the file exists or not(it will be created if necessary) and you also dont need to care about disposing or closing something as with the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: The problem is probably caused by the File.Create call that returns a stream. This stream should be disposed before you try to write that file with a different stream (AppendAllText opens a stream internally). So the answer is in the @TimSchmelter comment. Do not create the file if it doesn't exist. The AppendAllText will take care of that situation

Comment: @Steve This was the solution. Thanks for the help both of you ;)